# GHC undefined reference to Paths in dependency

Tags: haskell, linker, linker-errors, ghc, cabal

I recently made a cabal package which can be seen [here](https://github.com/rhofour/rlglue-haskell-codec/tree/v0.2.1.1)
It consists of a library and a few small example programs using it. Everything builds and works as expected.

I wanted to build an executable in a new package which uses this library, however I continue to run into a linking error I can't decipher:

```
/my/path/RandomAgent/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4/rlglue-0.2.1.1/libHSrlglue-0.2.1.1.a(Agent.o):(.text+0x34f1): undefined reference to `rlgluezm0zi2zi1zi1_Pathszurlglue_version1_closure'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
To make things simpler to diagnose I moved one of the examples programs into my new package and discovered even it won't build properly. You can find that version of the executable [here](https://github.com/rhofour/rlglue-random-agent/tree/v0.1.0.0).

From this I've concluded that the problem is likely in something I'm doing in my .cabal files, but I can't see what's wrong. The error also seems to refer to the Paths_rlglue module which cabal automatically generates for the first package.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the Paths_rlglue module in exposed-modules or other-modules like any other module in your project so that Cabal will link it.

Cabal should be better about telling you what is going on, see https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1746.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I missed something in the documentation for Paths_pkgname

> If you decide to import the Paths_pkgname module then it must be
>   listed in the other-modules field just like any other module in your
>   package.

Adding Paths_rlglue to my library's other-modules fixed the issue. Hope this saves someone all the time I lost on this.